# Apportable Setup

Tags: android, apportable

I've written a solution of how I got my project showing on my device using #Apportable, 
hope it helps someone.

**get your android device ready plugged in and turned on:**

- If your not already an android developer do the following:
- nexus 7>settings>about nexus 7>build number tap 6 times
- exit out of menu go to Developer options>USB debugging >turn this on
- ****check usb is turned on :P or you will get errors!)****
- now open command line:
- iMac:~ Minty$ cd
- drag and drop entire project **folder** onto command line tool screen
- iMac:~ Minty$ cd **/Users/Minty/Desktop/MyProjectFolder**/
- **dont forget to add the back slash**
- **iMac:MyProjectFolder Minty$** apportable load

console reads...Scanning build configuration for target MyProject

I had a couple of common errors.

- **No Java runtime present, requesting install.**
- fixed by loading http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US
- **- know what version of cocos2d you are using**
- (Cocos2D 1.X uses ES1, 2.X uses ES2) choose  [1/2]
- portrait orientation? (default: choose)[L/p]
- Should the app initially launch in landscape or portrait orientation?

console reads...Android device detected

console reads transfer complete pkg: /sdcard/MyProject-debug.apk

thats it you should now have it showing!

Comment: is it still working for you? does google still allows using Apportable to cross-combile iOS game to Android? as I unable to access main web page of Apportable right now.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my above post with my answer
hope it helps someone else